# how to get out of this infinite loop?

Tags: excel, vba

my folder contains many files. And I have similar folder for each months.  Datafiles are having same name but they are on different folders. What I want is to copy a specific column (computed result) of previous month's datafile to new month's datafile.

My code is

```
Dim fileName1, Pathname1 As String
Pathname1 = "c:\Charts\1\"
For Each vFile1 In vArr1
fileName1 = Dir(Pathname1 & vFile1 & "\" & "*.xlsx")
Do While fileName1 <> ""
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(Pathname1 & vFile1 & "\" & fileName1)
    WB1.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WB1.ActiveSheet.Columns("M").Copy
    WB1.Close (False)

For Each vFile In vArr
fileName = Dir(Pathname & vFile1 & "\" & "*.xlsx")

If fileName = fileName1 Then
Set WBD1 = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & vFile1 & "\" & fileName1)
 WBD1.ActiveSheet.Columns("C").Select
    WBD1.ActiveSheet.Paste
    WBD1.Close (True)
    Else
    End If

    Next
Loop
Next
```

What i am doing is 
1. open a file

2. copy a column
3. checking the filenames are same
4. if they are same paste the copied data

BUt the loop gets infinite.
I debugged and couldn't find it
pls help

Comment: Are you sure it's an infinite loop, and not just a very  inefficient algorithm that's taking a really long time?

Comment: ya i tried... Its going infinitely. what happens is once the condition is satisfied, its not moving to the second file. checking the same file again and again. I think its because the file is closed.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the DIR function with an argument it finds the first file that matches the specified criteria. If you want to get the next file, use DIR() on its own.

In your code you are getting the first file over and over again and never reaching the condition where filename1 = ""

Comment: se DIR() on its own means?!

Comment: When you use filename1=Dir(Pathname & vFile1 & "\" & "*.xlsx") it returns the first match. You need a line in your code that says filename1=Dir() to get the next and subsequent matches. You also need to fix your inner For...next loop as it is working through values of vFile, but you are using vFile1 instead of vFile.

Comment: thanks.. it goes to the second file and stops. showing error 1004